# Бинд айпи в локальной сети

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

3 меня есть 2 компьютера на базе Linux в одной локальной сети. Можно ли как-то с первого компьютера забиндить адрес второго для запуска какой-либо программы? Если да, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: А можете рассказать оригинальную задачу, а не то, как Вы ее понимаете? А то пока выглядит немного странно.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду выполнение системного вызова [bind](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)? (если его, то естественно, ответ **нет**; если не его, то объясните, что именно для вас означает *"бинд айпи"*)

Comment: нужно чтобы при запуске программы на первом компьютере, допустиим mysql, я мог использовать айпи второго компьютера, не проксированием, а чисто чтобы было задано y.y.y.y в идеале. В итоге чтобы доступ к mysql был только через айпи второго компьютера, а тот же порт первого компьютера я мог использовать под другую задачу

Answer (score 0):

Для именно **забиндить**

Можно сделать проброс портов через ssh.

Сервер 2 подключается к серверу 1 и забивает там порт. Сообщения передаются на локальный сокет.

```
ssh server1 -R 0.0.0.0:5000:127.0.0.1:5000
```

Хотя наверное Вам нужен **проброс порта**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:5000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -d 192.168.0.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Думаю такой вариант не подходит, надо именно биндить айпи, а не просто пересылать трафик

Comment: Так он забиндин) в варианте ссх